# How do I calculate the length of a curve given in parameterized form?

Tags: differential-geometry, multivariable-calculus

I am given a function describing a curve:

$f(t) = (f_1(t), f_2(t))',\quad t \in \mathbb{R},\quad  f_1, f_2: \ \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\ .$

How would I calculate the length of that curve corresponding to a given $t$-interval $[a, b]$?

Comment: Looks like it'd take a miracle to get $x$ from $r$ with known elementary functions. If there's some overarching problem you're working on that lurks behind all this write-up, I urge you to present it clearly if you want meaningful responses.

Comment: The lower part is pretty much my problem. I have a curve defined by two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ and I need to work with that curve, e.g. determine its length in a given interval.

Comment: It's utterly hopeless to get a general closed form solution for $x$ in terms of the variable $r$.  But if $r$ is kind of large, like $\gt 6$, the exponential makes virtually no difference. Without much trouble you can find excellent approximation for $x$ in terms of $r$. It is probably best to break up range into say $3$ parts, find different excellent approximating formulas over each part.

Comment: @Maria Gordova: Perhaps you might want to take a look at [arclength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length)? If you use the formula for parametric curves then you don't need to bother with finding a new $g$ function. Also, in English, we might say we "invert" a function if we go from $r=f(x)$ to $x=f^{-1}(r)$, but for mathematical expressions in general, saying you're "manipulating" or "rearranging" it is okay.

Comment: The length of an parametrized curve is pretty easy to find. Is that all you need to do?

Comment: @anon Thanks, I'll give it a try as it seems the way I was trying to solve it is a dead end.

Comment: @yatima2975 Yes and no. I need to find the point that lies halfway between a given start and end point (on the curve), so I gotta calculate the length $l$ and then find the upper limit for the integral from the start point with length $l/2$ via numeric integration (Mathematica 8 was a big help at that for easier functions in the past :-).

Comment: It would help if you could tell us what you are trying to do and where the problem came from. If you are doing this for a computer program or something similar, a numerical approximation might do well, or maybe you could change your functions slightly for something similar which will be possible to invert. Finding a symbolic answer is in general impossible or at least difficult, so if you don't need that you can get away much cheaper.

Comment: @Samuel That's all I'm trying to do. Basically I failed dealing with the parametrized form of the curve, which lead me to this difficult path, but the answer anon gave me seems to be what I need.

Comment: @anon I will re-write the question so you can put that Wikipedia link as answer (else I don't see how to 'save' this question :-)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The required length is given by the formula
$$L(\gamma|a,b)\ =\ \int_a^b\sqrt{\dot f_1^2(t)+\dot f_2^2(t)}\ dt\ .$$
There are two possibilities:

${\it Either}$ you find an elementary primitive $\Sigma(t)$ of the function $\sigma(t):=\sqrt{\dot f_1^2(t)+\dot f_2^2(t)}$. In this case the length is simply $=\Sigma(b)-\Sigma(a)$. Examples for such $\gamma$ are, e.g., parabolas, circles, logarithmic spirals, but not ellipses.

${\it Or}$ you have to resort to a numerical procedure. The simplest is to put $t_k:=a+k {b-a \over N}$ $\ (0\leq k\leq N)$  for some large $N$ and compute the following approximation:
$$L(\gamma|a,b)\ \dot=\ {b-a \over N}\Bigl({1\over 2}\bigl(\sigma(t_0)+\sigma(t_N)\bigr)+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1} \sigma(t_k)\Bigr)\ .$$

Comment: I can't follow the part where I need to find an elementary primitive. Can you explain, why it's not simply the formula mentioned at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) (ie. $L(a,b)\ =\ \int_a^b\sqrt{f_1'(t)^2+f_2'(t)^2}\ dt$)?

Comment: @Maria:  this is no different for arc length than other integrals.  There are many functions, like $\exp(-x^2)$ that we can't integrate in closed form.  Not knowing your $f_1$ and $f_2$ we may have the same problem.  But you can always do it numerically.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ah, I can follow. See, I'm not that much into mathematics and revert to Mathematica for such tasks, so I *am* solving this numerically, but let Mathematica do all the intermediate steps (yes, I'm fully aware that I don't learn anything that way ;)).